# What do these parts of Bukhari trying to say?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, hadith-interpretation, sahih-bukhari, singing

> Narrated Aisha:
>   Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) (p.b.u.h) came to my house while two girls were singing beside me the songs of Buath (a story about the war between the two tribes of the Ansar, the Khazraj and the Aus, before Islam). The Prophet (p.b.u.h) lay down and turned his face to the other side. Then Abu Bakr came and spoke to me harshly saying, "Musical instruments of Satan near the Prophet (p.b.u.h) ?" Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) (p.b.u.h) turned his face towards him and said, "Leave them." When Abu Bakr became inattentive, I signaled to those girls to go out and they left. It was the day of `Id, and the Black people were playing with shields and spears; so either I requested the Prophet (p.b.u.h) or he asked me whether I would like to see the display. I replied in the affirmative. Then the Prophet (p.b.u.h) made me stand behind him and my cheek was touching his cheek and he was saying, "Carry on! O Bani Arfida," till I got tired. The Prophet (p.b.u.h) asked me, "Are you satisfied (Is that sufficient for you)?" I replied in the affirmative and he told me to leave.
>
> Narrated Aisha:
>   That once Abu Bakr came to her on the day of `Id-ul-Fitr or`Id ul Adha while the Prophet (ﷺ) was with her and there were two girl singers with her, singing songs of the Ansar about the day of Buath. Abu Bakr said twice. "Musical instrument of Satan!" But the Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Leave them Abu Bakr, for every nation has an `Id (i.e. festival) and this day is our`Id.

Does this mean that women can sing or not?

Also, were the girls mentioned here mature or not?

Answer (score 1):

As-salamu alaikum! The mentioned ahadith show that the prophet, peace and blessings of Allah be upon him, allowed girls to sing in his presence on the day of Eid.

> It was narrated that Buraydah said: The Messenger of Allah, peace and
>   blessings of Allah be upon him, went out on one of his military
>   campaigns, and when he came back, a black slave woman came and said,
>   “O Messenger of Allah, I vowed that if Allah brought you back safe
>   and sound, I would beat the daff before you and sing. The Messenger of
>   Allah, peace and blessings of Allah be upon him, said, “If you vowed
>   that, then do it, otherwise do not do it.’...” (Jami at-Tirmidhi 3690)

The mentioned hadith above indicates that the prophet, peace and blessings of Allah be upon him, also allowed women to sing in his presence.

Therefore, girls as well as women are allowed to sing and men are allowed to listen to it, at least on special occasions.

Some additional ahadith to these matter:

> It was narrated from Anas bin Malik: that the Prophet, peace and
>   blessings of Allah be upon him, passed by some part of Al-Madinah and
>   saw some girls beating their daff and singing, saying: “We are girls
>   from Banu Najjar what an excellent neighbor is Muhammad.” The
>   Prophet, peace and blessings of Allah be upon him, said: “Allah knows
>   that you are dear to me.” 
>  (Sunan Ibn Majah; English reference:
>   Vol. 3, Book 9, Hadith 1899; Arabic reference: Book 9, Hadith 1974)
>
> It was narrated that 'Amir bin Sa'd said: "I entered upon Qurazah bin
>   Ka'b and Abu Mas'ud Al-Ansari during a wedding and there were some
>   young girls singing. I said: 'You are two of the Companions of the
>   Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings of Allah be upon him, who were
>   present at Badr, and this is being done in your presence!' They said:
>   'Sit down if you want and listen with us, or if you want you can go
>   away. We were granted a concession allowing entertainment at
>   weddings.' (Sunan an-Nasa'i 3383)